# "When you do things right, people won't be sure you've done anything at all" meaning

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

I am trying to understand the meaning of "won't be sure" in the following sentence from Futurama episode S03E20 - Godfellas.

> When you do things right, people won't be sure you've done anything at
> all.

In this case, my interpretation "people will not be sure you did not act at all" it doesn't seem to fit the context. Because it means that people think that you have done something. But the sentence is quite ambiguous and I don't understand the double negation influence in this context. I was wondering if there are any meanings that I did not catch. What I thought it could mean (without using double negatives to clarify) is "if you do things right, people think you sat on your hands."

I report the whole dialogue.

> God: Bender, being God isn't easy. If you do too much, people get
> dependent on you, and if you do nothing, they lose hope. You have to
> use a light touch. Like a safecracker, or a pickpocket.
>
> Bender: Or a guy who burns down a bar for the insurance money!
>
> God: Yes, if you make it look like an electrical thing. When you do things right,
> people won't be sure you've done anything at all.

Comment: What meaning did you attribute to the phrase? It would help to have that in the question so that the community can help work out what 'else' there might be.

Comment: In this case, if you commit arson "correctly" people won't realize it's arson.

Comment: For example a professional dancer smiles during a difficult performance, making all that hard work look easy, when it is not easy.

Comment: The Holy Spirit is sometimes referred to as the Unseen Helper. He's subtle, usually gentle, and doesn't seek acclaim for Himself. You have to really look to see Him ... but He's certainly at work.  And Jesus likewise advises us to imitate Himself: "Matthew 6:1 The Message The World Is Not a Stage
_Be especially careful when you are trying to be good so that you don’t make a performance out of it. It might be good theater, but the God who made you won’t be applauding." [[Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6%3A1&version=MSG)] Also, neat work is usually delicate.

Comment: "you did not act" has a negative. "you've done anything" does not.

Comment: The broad meaning is that what is done right will cause so few ripples, no-one one will notice any "doing"; the outcome will seem wholly natural, utterly uninfluenced by any "doing".

Whatever else, "people will not be sure you did not act at all" will be wrong. That negative will never work. Instead, you would need, for instance, the positive "people will not be sure (whether) you acted"